# Winforms ComboBox Height different to ItemHeight

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox

I am using a ComboBox in Text and DropDown mode (the default) and I want to have an `ItemHeight` of X (e.g. 40) but have the ComboBox's `Height` set to Y (e.g. 20).

The reason for this is that I am intending to use the ComboBox for a Quick Search feature in which the user keys in text and detailed results are rendered in the list items. Only one line of input is required.

Unfortunately, Winforms automatically locks the ComboBox's `Height` to the `ItemHeight` and I can see no way to change this.

How can I make the ComboBox's `Height` differ to the `ItemHeight`?

Comment: Please share the designer code for the control and a UI image for whats required

Comment: I mainly develop in Windows Phone, and there if I needed to implement such a quick search functionality I used a TextBox in which the user types, and under that a listview on which the search results are rendered. It worked out pretty well and gives lot of space for customization.

Comment: Have you tried to change DrawMode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have to do is, first of all, change `DrawMode` from `Normal` to `OwnerDrawVariable`. Then you've got to handle 2 events: `DrawItem` and `MeasureItem` . They would be something like:

```
    private void comboBox1_MeasureItem(object sender, MeasureItemEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ItemHeight = 40; //Change this to your desired item height
    }


    private void comboBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
    {
        ComboBox box = sender as ComboBox;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(null, box))
            return;

        e.DrawBackground();

        if (e.Index >= 0)
        {
            Graphics g = e.Graphics;

            using (Brush brush = ((e.State & DrawItemState.Selected) == DrawItemState.Selected)
                                  ? new SolidBrush(SystemColors.Highlight)
                                  : new SolidBrush(e.BackColor))
            {
                using (Brush textBrush = new SolidBrush(e.ForeColor))
                {
                    g.FillRectangle(brush, e.Bounds);

                    g.DrawString(box.Items[e.Index].ToString(),
                                 e.Font,
                                 textBrush,
                                 e.Bounds,
                                 StringFormat.GenericDefault);
                }
            }
        }

        e.DrawFocusRectangle();
    }
```